# Accessing lists within multidimentional tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am new to Python ..

I am able to generate the following output by comparing two dictionaries with `dictdiffer` and it is in `oo` variable:

```
oo = ('remove', '', [('we are here to help you improve your skills', [['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']]), ('(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', [['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']]), ('YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', [['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'], ['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']])])
('remove', '', [('we are here to help you improve your skills', [['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']]), ('(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', [['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']]), ('YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', [['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'], ['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']])])
('remove', '', [('we are here to help you improve your skills', [['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']]), ('(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', [['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']]), ('YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', [['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'], ['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']])])
```

I would like to access the **lists within this tuple**, with an output like:

```
['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']
['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']
['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']
 ......
 ......
```

What I did so far is simply `looping by index value`:

```
for tuple in enumerate(oo):
    for list in tuple[1]:
        for activity in list:
            print(activity[0])
```

However the output is with random letters and not every list (starting with date) is there!:

```
r
e
m
o
v
e
w
['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']
(
['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']
Y
['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']
```

How can I arrange lists and able to retrieve them from this multi tuple variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure seems to be tuples of tuples and lists.

The below seems to work to get the desired results.

```
oo = ('remove', '', [('we are here to help you improve your skills', [['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']]), ('(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', [['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']]), ('YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', [['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'], ['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']])])
('remove', '', [('we are here to help you improve your skills', [['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']]), ('(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', [['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']]), ('YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', [['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'], ['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']])])
('remove', '', [('we are here to help you improve your skills', [['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']]), ('(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', [['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']]), ('YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', [['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'], ['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']])])


for x in oo[2]:
    for y in x[1]: 
        print(y)
```

returns

```
['2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered']
['2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered']
['2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']
['2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered']
```